# Workflow issue getting email from multiline field

Tags: list, workflow, multiline-text-field

I've created a workflow that takes an email from a single line text field and uses it as a parameter in the "TO" field of sending email.

Everything worked.

But I had to change the field to multiline plain text, and now the email is no longer being sent.

When I see the field on Sharepoint list edit mode, Sharepoint put the e-mail into html a tag like:

```
 <a href="mailto:blabla@email.com">blabla@email.com</a>
```

When I switch back to single line text it works again, but I need to register multiple emails in the same field and single line text does not suit me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed the email field from single line to multiple lines, and this field came as an additional one from a lookup field.

Lookup fields do not allow additional columns of the multi-line type, but the workflow continued showing the field anyway.

My solution was to take this multi-line field through a lookup by the ID of the lookup field and put it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the settings of that multiline field to stop appending text.

[image]

Comment: "NO" is already checked!